# How can I build a URL query string based on a dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a URL query string dynamically based on several different parameters for an ecommerce site I am working on. The site is on a SaaS platform, so server side coding/scripting is out of the question.

**Requirements:**

Client wants to be able to perform a search based on "finish"—such as Chrome, Bronze, etc and on the "condition" (new/used/refurbished for instance).

The filters should be able to be added/removed from the URL string without impacting the other variables (such as ?find=search-term, &category=1234, etc).

**Current difficulty(s):**

Right now I cannot figure out a way to contruct the URL string dynamically based on the dropdown choice or how to make the dropdown choice persist after pageload until another option is selected.

**URL Example search query structure:** *http://www.domain.com/search.aspx?find=search-term&category=1234&bath-finish=chrome*

Current markup for example(s):

This is the HTML for the dropdown list I am working with so far for just the "Finish" option.

```
<select id="searchbox" name="URL">
<option>Choose Filter ...</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Chrome">Chrome</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Bronze">Bronze</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Black">Black</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Brass">Brass</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Copper">Copper</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Nickel">Nickel</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Stainless-Steel">Stainless Steel</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Gold">Gold</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Silver">Silver</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Brown">Brown</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=White">White</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Almond">Almond</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Bisquit">Bisquit</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Blue">Blue</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Clear">Clear</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Clear-Glass">Clear Glass</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Wood">Wood</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Green">Green</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Grey">Grey</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Satin">Satin</option>
<option value="&bath-finish=Oil-Rubbed">Oil Rubbed</option>
</select>
```

This is the script I had attempted to make so far (which only addresses the single filter):

```
<script>
var selectFilter= $('#searchbox').val();
$('#searchbox').on("change", function(e){
  document.location.href = 'http://www.domain.com/search.aspx?log=false' + selectFilter;
});
</script>
```

The main issue that I am having right now is that the script doesn't seem to read the selected option from the dropdown box and i'm not 100% sure why. Ideally, I'd like to have the URL be very modular so that the selections would have pretty tight control over the URL string.

Example:

domain.com/search.aspx?find=search-term&filter=selected-filter-value

Where "selected-filter-value" is based upon the selection in the dropdown box.

Comment: You're setting `selectFilter` when the page is loaded, not when the user selects from the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
    $('#searchbox').on("change", function(e){
        var selectFilter= $(this).val();
      document.location.href = 'http://www.domain.com/search.aspx?log=false' + selectFilter;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I felt like I was just making a silly mistake and it in fact appears I was. Do you know how I could get the dropdown value to persist even after the page reloads? Not the biggest deal I guess but it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you,

```
              <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function(){
                    $('#searchbox').on("change", function(){
                        var selectFilter= $(this).val();
                        document.location.href = 'http://www.domain.com/search.aspx?log=false' + selectFilter;
                    });
                }); 
            </script>
```